# Viewing data in nutch crawl/segment folder

Tags: nutch

I have a question regarding viewing data in `crawldb/segments` folder. I see there is a `content/part-00000` folder in segment folder. How do I dump the data (or view the data)?

This is what I am seeing when is type esc `:%!xxd` in the binary file (I removed the hex codes)

```
SEQ.org.apache.hadoop.io.Text 
org.apache.nutch.parse.ParseText.
.org.apache.hadoop.io.compress. 
DefaultCodec http://localhost:8001/a.html
```

and more characters like this.

It does not make much sense. This does not look like the data I have on the local page. Is there another way of looking at this or should I be looking at a different place?

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command from nutch home:

```
bin/nutch readseg -dump crawl/segments/your_segment output -nofetch -noparse -noparsetext
```

To know what commands you can use with Nutch, try to run

```
bin/nutch
```

I hope that helps.